# iOS Simulator for iPad not working since upgrade to Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

A few days back I upgraded to Xcode 4.3.2 by downloading from the developer's portal and running the installation files. Since then, I am able to test apps on my devices and am also able to test them on the iOS simulator for iPhone without issues. However, the iPad simulator is not working well. A screenshot is attached.

1. The home button doesn't appear.
2. The status bar doesn't appear.
3. The simulator appears like a window with minimize and maximize icons (only the maximize icon is enabled) and also has a title with the version no.

Can anyone please advise, a screenshot of the simulator is present at the below location.
http://postimage.org/image/68pa1t7l9/

Comment: If I set the Window - Scale Size to 50% I am able to see the status bar, but the home button is still not visible.

Comment: I have the same window. I guess there is nothing to do about it...

Comment: Too bad then from Apple. Surprised, how come they have made such howlers with Xcode 4.3.2. Firstly, you cannot see the upgrade from AppStore if you were in 4.2 and now this. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

The Skins are missing from the iPad simulator, a solution is using the keyboard shortcuts, Cmd+Shift+H for Home, Cmd+1 / 2 / 3 to resize the window to fit on your screen to avoid scrollbars and such.